# Make the Stack Exchange Hot Questions feed include all HNQs

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, feed

I noticed that the [Stack Exchange Hot Questions feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions) only comprises the 30 topmost HNQs rather than [all 100](https://stackexchange.com/). I wonder why that is and if there is a good reason for it, when the complete list isn't unhealthily large either with just 100 instead of 30.

I would thus hereby propose to **extend the feed to include all 100 HNQs** rather than just the top 30.